# Accessing Twitter Accounts UIAlertView

Tags: ios, xcode, twitter

I remember many times having apps that would pop up an alertview saying the app wanted my permission to access Twitter accounts.  Is that something that has to be handled by the app itself, or does that get automatically called with

```
requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                              completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
```

This is in regards to iOS 6 only, not any other versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the dialog `“Application” Would Like Access to Twitter Accounts` it gets called automatically the first time. Further requests are ignored until the user enables access manually in Settings > Privacy > Twitter.

Comment: Thanks.  Reset the privacy setting and it prompted me for it again.  I guess a long time ago I had allowed it.